# How do I get a single Ingress to be handled by just one of two HAProxy Ingress Controllers on AKS?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, haproxy-ingress

I have two separate IngressControllers, one internal and one external. I would like to define which controller to use for each Ingress.

I have defined `--ingress.class=hapxroxy-ext` arg for the external controller and `--empty-ingress-class` for the internal.

Ingress Services

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
  labels:
    run: ext-haproxy-ingress
  name: ext-haproxy-ingress
  namespace: ext-haproxy-controller
spec:
  selector:
    run: ext-haproxy-ingress
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    "service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal": "true"
  labels:
    run: haproxy-ingress
  name: haproxy-ingress
  namespace: haproxy-controller
spec:
  selector:
    run: haproxy-ingress
  type: LoadBalancer
```

I have IngressClasses.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: IngressClass
metadata:
  name: external-lb
spec:
  controller: haproxy.org/ingress-controller/hapxroxy-ext
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: IngressClass
metadata:
  name: internal-lb
  annotations:
    "ingressclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class": "true"
spec:
  controller: haproxy.org/ingress-controller
```

I have one Ingress

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    "kubernetes.io/ingress.class": internal-lb
spec:
  ingressClassName: internal-lb
...
```

Despite mapping the Ingress to just `internal-lb`, both `internal-lb` and `external-lb` handle requests.

It seems pretty straightforward in the [docs](https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/kubernetes/latest/configuration/controller/#--ingressclass), but I'm missing something.

Comment: Opened a GitHub issue as well https://github.com/haproxytech/kubernetes-ingress/issues/354

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is due to a bug in https://github.com/haproxytech/kubernetes-ingress when using IngressClassName in ingress.yaml. If you remove IngressClassName from your ingress.yaml and just use   "kubernetes.io/ingress.class": annotation the issue goes away, it more of a workaround than a fix.

This issue has been raised and still open see link below for updates.

https://github.com/haproxytech/kubernetes-ingress/issues/354#issuecomment-904551220